# Duda ej. Java funcion Length contar letras

Tags: java

Hola buenas noches estoy intentando hacer este ejercicio

**Escribir un programa que pregunte el nombre del usuario en consola,
el programa debe mostrar el mensaje “(nombre) tiene (n) letras”,
donde (nombre) es el nombre del usuario y (n) es el número de letras
que tiene el nombre.**

Estoy usando la función Length pero el programa me marca error

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejercicio3 {
    public static void main(String[] Args){
        String nombre ;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        int length = nombre.length();
        System.out.println("Su nombre tiene",(nombre.length()),"Letras");
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca el error que te sale.

Comment: method java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Y leiste la documentacion de la funcion println? porque asi no es como se le pasan los parametros....

Comment: Estás pidiendo una longitud de caracteres a un String que no contiene nada, no le has puesto un valor a tu variable 'nombre'.

Comment: Siempre que digas que tira un error, el error debe ir en la pregunta.. no somos adivinos ;)

Answer (score 6):

Tienes varios errores:

1. Como buena práctica, siempre inicializa las variables.
2. Podrías ver los métodos de las clases y los tipos que devuelven antes de usarlos.
3. Las clases en Java siempre deben comenzar en mayúscula.
4. `int length = nombre.length();` esto provoca error nuca obtienes un valor en la variable nombre, no puedes saber la longitud.
5. `nombre = entrada.nextLine();` esto es mejor. Desde el teclado escribes la cadena, después obtienes la longitud `nombre.length()` que al final si es de tipo int.
6. `System.out.println(" Algo ", (otracosa), " otra");` no existe en Java, está mal su uso. Puedes concatenar si quieres imprimir en consola. System.out.println("Suma de 5 + 4 da "+(5+4)+" en total"); Incluso usar `int num = 4;System.out.printf("Numero %d\n",num);` si quieres darle un formato.

**Ejercicio.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String nombre = "";
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Su nombre tiene "+nombre.length()+" letras");
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Referencias:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: Te falto explicarle los problemas en su metodo println...

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @gbianchi